# PHP Image Resizing Does NOT Resize In Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, image-resizing

I am having a very interesting problem. The script I wrote below works, but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer. The MAX_WIDTH variable is set to 450 and it still uploads the image with the original dimensions of the image, not 450 by whatever the conversion factor is. Any suggestions? It works and resizes in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. Also, the version of IE I am testing on is IE 8 64-bit version. Thanks.

```
private function checkForResize() {
    $fileTypeArray = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $origType = $this->_uploadType;
    if (in_array($origType, $fileTypeArray)) {
        $origImage = $_FILES[$this->_uploadInputField]['tmp_name'];
        $imageWidth = getimagesize($origImage);
        if ($imageWidth[0] > MAX_WIDTH) {
            // Resize here
            if ($origType == 'image/gif') {
                $imageSrc = imagecreatefromgif($origImage);
            } else if ($origType == 'image/jpeg') {
                $imageSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($origImage);
            } else if ($origType == 'image/png') {
                $imageSrc = imagecreatefrompng($origImage);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            $width = $imageWidth[0];
            $height = $imageWidth[1];
            $newHeight = ($height / $width) * MAX_WIDTH;
            $tmpImage = imagecreatetruecolor(MAX_WIDTH, $newHeight);
            $this->setTransparency($tmpImage, $imageSrc);
            imagecopyresampled($tmpImage, $imageSrc, 0, 0, 0, 0, MAX_WIDTH, $newHeight, $width, $height);
            imagejpeg($tmpImage, UPLOAD_DIR.DS.$this->_uploadSafeName, 100);
            imagedestroy($imageSrc);
            imagedestroy($tmpImage);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: php runs server side, it does not know what a browser is

Comment: You'll have to debug a little here. Is the image *really* not being resized? Maybe it's just a problem in how it's displayed in the browser. Put some debugging statements in to see if all of that code is executed as expected. If the image is uploaded and read correctly by `imagecreatefrom*`, there should be no difference based on the browser.

Comment: but see thats the thing. i can upload the same image in chrome and turn around a upload the same exact image in ie but one gets resized down to 450 in chrome and not in ie. i am looking directly at the files themselves and in a browser.

Comment: Did you check the HTML form code? Can you paste it here?

Comment: @mani my form code is perfectly fine. everything processes fine. just a resizing issue and the code is posted in the original topic.

Comment: I was asking because you posted your PHP script that has nothing to do with browser issues like you said you have image resizing working fine when you are using chrome it means your PHP script is fine. Problem may have in your HTML code from where maybe you are missing some tags. Firefox / Chrome ignore some HTML issues but IE always make problem in client side script. You mush double check it.

Comment: Maybe IE doesn't send the correct mimetype of the images?

Comment: @tktutorials IE sometimes sends an `image/pjpeg` or `image/x-png` mime types, that might be an issue

Comment: @DamienPirsy that was the issue. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR TELLING ME THAT! Everything works great now.

Comment: Good. I wrote that as an answer, so that people seeing this question in the future would understand what the issue was without having to read all comments. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

The browser has nothing to do with server-side scripts going wrong, as it's on the client side.

What can be wrong, though, is the fact that MIME type is an unreliable information, for it's the browser who detects and sends the MIME type.

And IE sometimes sends an `image/pjpeg`  or an `image/x-png` MIME type when dealing with jpgs or pngs, so you need to check those also when validating.